# oauth2.0 how to pass access token

Tags: http, rest, curl, oauth-2.0

I am working on integrating *OAuth2* to a *REST API* and I would like to know how am I supposed to send the **access_token** parameter for the requests.

**Example:**
My server accepts two routes:
POST /write
GET /read

For /write, am I supposed to put the access_token in the POST?
`curl http://api.localhost/write -d 'access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]'`

For /read, am I supposed to put it in the GET?
`curl http://api.localhost/read?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]`

Or in both cases, is it supposed to be sent through POST?

Thanks,
Gasim

Comment: Note that both `/write` and `/read` do **NOT** follow the RESTful API standards. Resource names should be collections, not verbs. HTTP already has its own set of verbs. For example if your API reads/writes files, then the end point should be `/files` and `GET` request would read a file, while `PUT` or `POST` should create a file. (`PUT` if your client specifies the ID, `POST` if the server does)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

With OAuth, the token is generally passed in the request headers. You may wish to try something similar to the following, for both POST or GET:

POST: `curl http://api.localhost/write -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN'`

GET: `curl http://api.localhost/read -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN'`

The value part of the Authorization key/value pair can vary by REST service provider. With [Github](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-oauth-token-for-command-line-use), for instance, the header key/value pair looks like this:

`curl -H "Authorization: token your_token" https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo`

You may need to consult the webservice provider docs for details.

Comment: @user984832  is the word `Bearer` is a keyword or does it a part of the access token

Comment: `Bearer` is a keyword used frequently by sites implementing OAuth 2.

Comment: How did u switch from api.localhost/read to https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo??

Comment: POST with curl should add the `-X` : The -X option specifies which HTTP request method will be used when communicating with the remote server.