# How to pass access_token in API using kong gateway

Tags: api, curl, request, access-token, kong

How to pass access_token in API using Kong API gateway?? I have tried the below:

```
https://10.223.98.237:8000/API_analytics/AnalyticsInputHisto‌​ryController?user=1/‌​oauth_callback#acces‌​s_token=1234567890&t‌​oken_type=Bearer&exp‌​ires_in=3600
```

and

```
http://10.223.98.237:8000/API_analytics/AnalyticsInputHistor‌​yController?user=1&a‌​ccess_token=12345678‌​90
```

kindly help me out with the proper syntax of API. Thank you

Comment: did you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like do from frontend using AJAX you can try this,

```
$.ajaxSetup(
    'headers': {
      'auth_token': "my_Token"
    }
  )
```

Here is the `KONG API` method,

```
curl -X POST http://10.223.98.237:8000/API_analytics/AnalyticsInputHistor‌​yController \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"name": "request-transformer", "config": {"add": {"headers": ["user:1,"a‌​ccess_token:12345678‌​90"}}}'
```

or

```
curl -X POST http://10.223.98.237:8000/API_analytics/AnalyticsInputHistor‌​yController \
  --data "name=request-transformer" \
  --data "config.add.headers='user':1,'a‌​ccess_token':12345678‌​90"
```

Comment: I obtained the access_token, the thing I am for is how to pass it, in my URL.Thanks for your time.

Comment: this is POST method you want get ?

Comment: No, GET method.

Comment: with reference to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334276/oauth2-0-how-to-pass-access-token

Comment: What I want is to enable the authorization through URL parameter like this: `http://10.223.98.237:8000/API_analytics/AnalyticsInputHistor‌​yController?user=1&a‌​ccess_token=12345678‌​90`

Comment: get was not in  kong api.

Comment: if its rest or other you can try like above answer using get itself